# CSS Positioning relative to particular element on HTML page

Tags: html, css

Positioning in CSS is one of the most interesting topics , so in absolute and relative positioning we position with respect to page, can anyone explain me how can i position an element with respect to another element on same page like for instance i have html page like.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <style>
 .block{
  display:block;
 }

</head>
<body>
<div class="container1 block"> content</div>
content here.....//can be img a or whatever html tag.
<div class="randomContainers"> <div class="container2 block"> </div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

So here in the code above, **how can i position div.container1 with respect to div.container2?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/4yzLo9ev/

You will need to set parent to `position:relative` of the parent `position:absolute` element

```css
.relative {
  position: Relative;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 200px;
}
.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  bottom: -75px;
  left: 25px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background: url(http://placeimg.com/150/150/any);
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">
  <div class="absolute"></div>
</div>
```

> An element with **position:absolute** will be positioned according to the
>   coordinates specified in its 'top' and 'left' attributes, relative to
>   the nearest positioned ancestor. Or it will get positioned according to the **window**

As shown in the below fiddle the you can see the `body` `height` `green-border`

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/4yzLo9ev/1/)

> If you want to get the positioned absolute div positioned according to
>   the body, body should be positioned relative

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/4yzLo9ev/2/)

> If both the parent and grand parent is relative the div will align to
>   the nearest parent

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/4yzLo9ev/3/)

Comment: That was helpful , but i'd like to know about the case when relative and absolute are not related as parent-child, can you extend it for that? or maybe i just have to do it with respect to common parent i.e body tag and make body relative and container1 and container2 absolute?